# Fancybox 3 iframe resizing problems

Tags: iframe, fancybox

I'll preface this by saying I'm an absolute amateur trying to make a very simple static website for a small charity, so assume you're talking to an idiot.

- I want 3 differently sized fancybox iframes on one page that show map
  locations.

I have these, but currently the size of all of the boxes is the default size of the browser window, which is far too large.

- I've tried to resize them the way the documentation states with CSS
  but as the website is responsive, at smaller sizes the height *never*
  expands beyond the browser window so the bottom of the iframe is
  always cut off.

  The demos for fancybox heavily imply that iframes should resize automatically but no amount of messing about with the css or my clumsy attempts at javascript changes them.

I'd have included code but I deleted all of my attempts and right now literally just have 3 vanilla fancybox iframes in my html.

Comment: Could you explain "at smaller sizes the height never expands beyond the browser window so the bottom of the iframe is always cut off." - any demo/screenshot would help.

Comment: I can give  you a screenshot if it helps https://www.flickr.com/photos/150339844@N08/shares/c328Ts

Comment: The first image is how the iframes are by default, the second is when the window is resized the rest of the text underneath becomes unavailable, it won't scroll down. I've tried previously changing the sizes by css and that will make them look the right size *until* the resolution is changed. I'm thinking there should be a way to do change dimensions on the fly.

Comment: Auto sizing is enabled by default, but it works only if content of iframe is accessible. Looks like your iframe is probably on other domain that main page. You can set custom css class (using `slideClass` option) for each of them to set custom dimensions.